# Hexo permalink repeat with folder path

Tags: hexo

I specify [the permalinks as DOCS says](http://hexo.io/docs/permalinks.html):
**`:category/:title`**

and for a given post named `hello-world.md` in `source/_posts` folder with the following content:

`title: Hello World
date: 2015-03-22 22:22:22
categories:
- foo`

and the permalinks will be **`foo/hello-world`**

But if I move this post to `source/_posts/foo`folder, and rename to `hello-world-2.md` the permalinks will be **`foo/foo/hello-world-2`**. Shows as the following image:

[image: like this]

Why the permalinks contains folder path?  If I have many posts, is it necessary to put all the posts in a folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Hexo as all other static site generators follows your directory structure. So if you create a directory named `foo` the URLs for the posts in this directory will contain the `foo` path.
2. Yes. If you don't want want a subrirectory URL path you should put all your files in the `_posts` directory.